# I am using heroku to test my application. how to solve cors problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors

Error:
I am using heroku to test my application. Back (node ​​js - express) frontend written in react

When entering the site, an error occurs when receiving data

How to deal with it

```
Access to fetch at 'my-web_api/allCity' from origin 'my-web_api' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to install cors(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) package to avoid this type of error

```
npm i cors
```

and use it in your server.js file just like that

```
 const cors = require('cors')
 app.use(cors())
```

Comment: please, how else can you solve this problem? I can't solve this problem for 5 hours anymore. tried to set cors: 'no-cors' in the request, but still gives an error

Comment: @HLEBHLEB Just have a look at this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/
This will solve the issue. You need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin.